# Why does the characteristic curve (V vs I) for a light bulb backbend?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, condensed-matter, electrical-resistance

When teaching Ohm's Law, I have students do an exploration of a small, incandescent light bulb with a low frequency (1-2 Hz) sine wave. It's a simple series circuit of source and light bulb, monitoring the current and voltage. The results are definitely non-linear due to temperature-dependent resistance of the filament. Surprisingly, however, the curvature is not uniformly positive or negative. As seen in the picture, there is a "backbend" in the curve near the extrema of the voltage.  If one interpreted this "ohmically", one might say the resistance becomes infinite, then negative, before passing back through infinity before becoming positive again.

[image: Light bulb characteristic curve at low frequency]

I understand the basic temperature dependence of a warming filament having an increasing resistance (and hence an increasing slope), but I'm puzzled by the backbend potion of the curve.  Is there a physics (condensed matter? thermodynamic?) explanation for it?

Edit: For clarification, the backbends occur on the way toward as the voltage approaches the + and - amplitudes. The smooth curvature occurs as the filament cools as the voltage drops away from the amplitudes toward zero.

Edit 2: In the first quadrant, for example, the path is counterclockwise as time increases. Same in the third quadrant, so the data paths cross over at V=0.  The light trace in the third quadrant is the beginning trace when the filament was initially at room temperature and began to warm.

Edit 3: Below is a trace using a triangle voltage input of amplitude 2 V at frequency 0.01 Hz collecting at a 20 Hz rate. There seems to be a sudden change in the resistivity of this filament once it reaches a certain temperature.

[image: Triangle voltage 2V at 0.01 Hz]

Comment: Can you re-clarify?  :)   In the first quadrant,  does the trace go clockwise or counterclockwise?  Third quadrant (thick line)?  What is the faint line in the third quadrant?

Comment: @garyp See Edit 2

Comment: I don't know, but I would run this at lower and higher frequencies to see what  happens.  Might get a hint. Could a stray inductance cause this?

Comment: I haven't done a detailed frequency profile, but by 60 Hz, the slope is constant (ohmic?). Stray inductance might be a good starting point. Anyone who wants to submit that analysis is welcome!

Comment: You are tracing the curve too fast and you are seeing the time lag between change of the voltage and the actual change of the temperature. Trace at 0.1Hz or slower and the problem will go away.

Comment: @CuriousOne Even at 0.07 Hz, the backbend occurs. It did eventually quit bending backwards when I reduced the frequency to 0.01 Hz, but there is still a sudden, sharp change in the resistance which indicates a sudden change in resistivity. There is also a small hysteresis in the V-I curve, even at that slow a change. I will add the curve to the question.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for sharing the new results. Looking forward to the new curve. I have a hunch of what else may be going on but I want to see the result first.

Comment: Well, actually, this looks quite reasonable to me. I was expecting an instability with a very sudden onset of power consumption (coupled with a sharp temperature and resistivity increase) for the case where the filament is being driven by a controlled current, rather than a voltage source. This could also happen if the current measuring shunt resistor has a much higher resistance than the cold filament, but I am not sure you are seeing that.

Comment: @CuriousOne The low current slope is about 1 $\Omega$ and the high current slope is about 13 $\Omega$. The shunt resistance is 1 $\Omega$.  I haven't done a quantitative measurement of the brightness, but there is a definite difference in the 1 V brightness and the 2 V brightness which would indicate a change in temperature. There doesn't, however, seem to be a change in resistivity between 1 and 2 V. Why the sudden change in resistivity between 0.1 and 0.5 V?

Comment: The heating power is $P=RI^2=U^2/R$, i.e. when you change the voltage by a factor of 5 (assuming that the resistance stays roughly equal), then the power will change by a factor of 25. The power-temperature dependence of the filament is a complicated function, because you have to take both conducted cooling (trough the leads and the glass body) and radiative cooling into account. The latter has a very steep dependence on the temperature due to Stefan-Boltzman: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law, which has a $P\propto T^4$ form.

Comment: I would guess that at low power/temperature cooling is basically trough the leads and it's more or less proportional to the temperature difference to the environment, but at some point the radiative cooling takes over and there is this steep dependence of temperature, which means one has to put a lot more power in to make the filament even slightly hotter, which means that the resistance will also not change very fast from that point on.

Comment: @CuriousOne You should compose an answer from the comments and post it.  I still wonder whether the temperature coefficient of resistivity is playing a factor: is it constant or does it change dramatically.  Like you said, the temperature is complicated.  I hadn't thought about the environmental cooling due to the external connections of the bulb socket. Definitely some real world physics.

Comment: I have answered this kind of question before, but to be honest with you, for one I am too lazy to analyze this in detail, for another I don't believe that there is a simple and elegant closed form solution to this system, so one probably will end up bogged down having to solve forth order equations, or worse (there are, at least, first, second and forth powers involved in the equations between voltage/current/temperature and resistance). It's a nice, simple experiment for high school and freshman level experimental physics, but it's not really that interesting in terms of fundamentals.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Your comment which begins "The heating power is P=RI 2 =U 2 /R" is only partly true, since it assumes that R is constant. In fact, R changes by more than an order of magnitude over the range from zero to full brightness.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: That's why there is the "(assuming that the resistance stays roughly equal)" disclaimer... and the comment was only relevant for the low temperature regime of the filament before it gets really hot. The temperature dependence of the resistivity of metals is a tough nut and technically it's usually measured and fitted with some higher order polynomials... so that's another reason why I wouldn't want to get into a detailed analysis. There are just too many non-trivial functional dependencies here to make this a happy analysis.

Comment: Is this vacuum, inert gas or halogen lightbulb? It may be of importance. I once saw very similar characteristic for old crystal point-contact diode.

Comment: @Niuthon It is a  small 3.5 V rated filament "flashlight" bulb. I don't know what the supporting gas is.  I buy them from PASCO.

Comment: I just replicated the experiment, same results. For higher frequencies I get an ellipse, probably due to induction in the filament? It's a coil after all. No idea about the bend though...

Answer (score 2):

The hysteresis seen is a result of the 'thermal inertia' of the filament. It goes away if the voltage is varied slowly enough for electrical power input to be the same as the power lost to the surroundings. For an experiment doing this and a mathematical model of the problem see 'Datalogging and Modelling I-V Curves' in my teacher resources https://sites.google.com/view/sgt-physics/home